# How do I to read a github file with python in the same repository?

Tags: python, github, machine-learning, repository, streamlit

I keep getting a FileNotFoundError when I try to open a file in the same repository with my code. I want to use 'classifier_model.pkl' in 'SpecLines_App'

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pickle
import pandas as pd

#https://github.com/mblk3/MLM_Atomic_Spec_Lines/blob/02f6a04db06b459169ea0d19c347146ea1ad17d8/classifier_model.pkl
#joblibFile = open('code_/classifier_model.pkl', 'rb')
#joblibFile = open(url, 'rb')
#model = pickle.load(joblibFile)

model = pd.read_pickle(r'classifier_model.pkl')
```

^This is what I've tried, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

How could I open this?

streamlit: classify-atomic-spec-lines.streamlit.app

github: github.com/mblk3/MLM_Atomic_Spec_Lines

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: How are you running this? Whether it works or not depends on the working directory.

Comment: Try running the file from the same directory. Alternatively, provide the complete file path to pd.read_pickle(). It's difficult to know what the problem is without knowing your file structure, the command you ran, where you're running the command from, and possibly the specific error that you're receiving.

Comment: @Chris I'm using streamlit to run - https://classify-atomic-spec-lines.streamlit.app (https://github.com/mblk3/MLM_Atomic_Spec_Lines). I've tried different file paths, and I copied directly from github path. Is there something different I should be using

Comment: @Sal sorry, yes here is the github: github.com/mblk3/MLM_Atomic_Spec_Lines and the streamlit error: classify-atomic-spec-lines.streamlit.app

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to open a relative pathname, so
[CWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)
will matter. You can learn what it is using:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

Consider doing a `cd` to a new directory before running this program.

---

Opening an absolute pathname may be preferrable.

This should obtain the location of your git repository:

```
from pathlib import Path
...
repo_top = Path(__file__ + "/..").resolve()
print(repo_top)
model = pd.read_pickle(repo_top / 'classifier_model.pkl')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `classifier_model.pkl` file does not exist in the **current git branch** from where your streamlit app `SpecLines_App` is being run.
Hence, you are getting the `FileNotFoundError`.

To solve this, there are at least two solutions. Choose which one works better for your needs:

1. Include the `classifier_model.pkl` file in your **current** git branch.
   Then `model = pd.read_pickle('classifier_model.pkl')` should work.
2. Download the `classifier_model.pkl` file at runtime **if it does not exist** (example code bellow):

```py
...
import requests
from pathlib import Path

def download_model():
    url = 'https://github.com/mblk3/MLM_Atomic_Spec_Lines/raw/02f6a04db06b459169ea0d19c347146ea1ad17d8/classifier_model.pkl'
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(url)
    open(local_filename, 'wb').write(response.content)

def is_model_found(file):
    model_path = Path(file)
    found = model_path.is_file()
    if not found:
        st.write(f"DEBUG: File `{model_path.absolute()}` not found. Let's download it! :arrow_down:")
        download_model()
    else:
        st.write(f"DEBUG: File `{model_path.absolute()}` found! :sunglasses:")
...

model_filename = "classifier_model.pkl"
is_model_found(model_filename)
model = pd.read_pickle(model_filename)
```